# Vue.js not displaying image with path sting loaded dynamically

Tags: image, vue.js, display

Vue.js not displaying image with path sting loaded dynamically

I am trying to display image in Vue.js.  Image path string is loaded from the database.

If I enter a static string it will work:

```html
<img :src="require('../../images/products/15/15.png')" width="100px" height="100px" />
<img src="@/images/products/15/15.png" width="100px" height="100px" />
```

However, if I get the image path via a variable, it wouldn’t work.

Example:

```html
<img src=“getImageStr()” height="100px" />
<img src=“getImageStr()” height="100px" />
```

in methods:

```
methods: {
    getImageStr(){
        return “../../images/products/15/15.png”;  //this works
        return require(‘@/images/products/15/15.png’); //this works

        var str = “../../images/products/15/15.png”;
        var str2 = “@/images/products/15/15.png”
        return str;  //fails
        return require(str2); //fails. 
    }
}
```

What could be going on? How can I fix this?  I din't know image rendering could be such an drama.

Comment: Did you try `return '${str}'` and load like `:src="require(str)" ` ?

Comment: Rather it returned an error: Cannot find module ".

Comment: Each time I use require with a dynamic string, it always return Cannot find module '.' error.